# Detecting Click on "Set wallpaper" button in Live Wallpaper Picker

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I have a live wallpaper that has more than one "skins", and the user is able to choose between the skins in the "Settings" menu. What I would like to achieve is the following: when the user sets a live wallpaper and then navigates again to the live wallpaper picker, I want him/her to be able to see how other skins look like in the preview but I want to change the skin of the live wallpaper that has already been set only when the user clicks the "Set wallpaper" button again.
In order to achieve this, I would need to detect the click on the "Set wallpaper" button from the live wallpaper picker. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the wallpaper is running as a preview with `isPreview()` inside [WallpaperService.Engine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/wallpaper/WallpaperService.Engine.html) and change the options.